# Hide div and don't show it again

Tags: javascript, toggle, onmouseover

I have this code that shows and hides two divs when "onmouseover".

```
   function hide_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if (e.style.display == 'none') e.style.display = 'block';
       else e.style.display = 'none';
   }
```

What I want is: when I do the mouseover it hides the div permanently and when I go over again it won't show anymore.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XmXjmx

THANKS!

Comment: Its a very self explainable answer

Answer (score 4):

You can just remove any code that sets `e.style.display` to `block`.

```
function hide_visibility(id) {
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   e.style.display = 'none';
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ojbzbK

Answer (score 1):

You could just set the html code to blank like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $( "#item" ).mouseover(function() {
        $( "#item" ).html(""); //Set html contents of #item to empty
    });

});
```

Of course you will not be able to unhide this content again as you have removed the `html` code. This will not matter though if there will not be a need for the element to be made visible again.